# Get Permalink for the top level parent of child pages

Tags: pages, child-pages

I've this pages structure:

- TOP PAGE

  - SUB PAGE 1

    - SUB SUB PAGE 1
  - SUB PAGE 2

  [etc]

Is it possible to display on each sub page a link to come back to the top level page? And how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to get the top page url:

```
$top_page_url = get_permalink( array_slice( get_ancestors( get_the_ID(), 'page' ) , -1 ) );
```

where `get_ancestors()` returns an array containing all the parents (ID) of the given page. You can read more about it in the Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687358/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-last-element-of-an-array-without-deleting-it) are various ways to get the last array item, but note that `end()` doesn't expects a function as an input - more about it in the PHP docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the post ID of the parent page with `$post->post_parent`; at that point, it's just a matter of using that ID to get the permalink.

This snippet from the wp.org forums will do what you need:

```
<?php if($post->post_parent) {
    $parent_link = get_permalink($post->post_parent); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $parent_link; ?>">Link to parent page</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Code snippet [found here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/link-to-parent-page?replies=12).

Comment: This will return the immediate parent, not necessarily the top level parent as requested. Think about what would happen with children nested 3 or 4 deep.

Comment: Good point -- I missed the "sub sub" when I first read the question!